# Call javascript function on this ASP.net webform on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio

How do I call this javascript function on this ASP.net webform on a button click? I added the .js file in the application but for some reason the button is not being able to refer to the .js file. I am getting a Javascript runtime error saying: divName is undefined. What am I doing wrong? Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Javascript code (The file is check.js):

```
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 20;

function addInput(divName) {

    if (counter == limit) {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    } else {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML =
            "Dimension Type " +
            "<br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>" + "Dimension " +
            "<br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";

        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
    }
  return true;
}
```

The ASP.Net button code:

```
          <p class="auto-style9">

        <script src="check.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return addInput(divName);" />


    </p>
    <p class="auto-style9">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your JS function to `return true` or `false` to prevent postback and change `OnClientClick` as below

```
OnClientClick="return addInput('divDimensions');"
```

Update HTML on ASPX page as below.

```
<script src="check.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="divDimensions"></div>
<p class="auto-style9">
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return addInput('divDimensions');" />
</p>
```

To follow the current webform format update else condition in JS as below

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableChecksheet");
var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.className = "auto-style3"
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "<h2>Dimension Type</h2>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<br><input id='txtDimensionType" + counter + "' type='text' name='myInputs[]' style='width: 500px;'>";

var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.className = "auto-style3"
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "<h2>Dimension</h2>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<br><input type='text' id='txtDimension" + counter + "'name='myInputs[]' style='width: 500px;'>";

counter++;
```

And in HTML give your main table an id `tableChecksheet` as below

```
<table align="center" class="auto-style2" id="tableChecksheet">
```

Comment: I updated the code as you said but the fields are not being generated as I click the button. For the updated version of my code, please see above on my original code. What am I doing wrong? Do I need a script line like the one in html: <script src="check.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>? If yes, then how will the script be in asp.net. I don't think I can use a HTML button.

Comment: Sure you need to reference your script file and you can do like HTML as you mention

Comment: So I referenced the script but it's still not working. I'm totally confused. It's giving me the following error: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: can you update the question with full HTML of ASPX page

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Is there any way I can transfer the values entered in these generated fields to a SQL server?

Comment: You can but not easy using current solution, try to use JS framework like Angular

Comment: Also, as of now the text boxes are not aligned with the field names. How do you make sure that the added fields follow the current webform format?

Comment: It worked again! Thank you so much, you are a savior! Just a thought. I was thinking if I can give the generated fields an id just like the fields that are already in the form. For example, the DimensionType field in the form has the Textbox Id="txtdimensiontype" and if the generated DimensionType field also has this same id, then perhaps the same id values can be stored in the SQL table under the DimensionType category? I updated my orginal code with the SQL string so that you can get an idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: Welcome, Check updated answer for setting id for textbox

Comment: I added the id but the value from the generated field didn't get stored in the SQL table. Do you think a change needs to be made in the JS function or C# code so that everytime the user enters something in the generated field, another new row will be automatically created in the SQL table with value typed in the generated field?

Comment: generated textboxes cannot be accessed from C# code, it should be asp:TextBox so you can call them from C# code

Answer (score 2):

You should specify just the function call, *without* the `javascript:` prefix:

```
OnClientClick="addInput(divNAME);"
```

Also some things that may need your attention:

- There must exist a global javascript variable `divNAME` with a proper value, because it is used in the above js call.
- You define a local variable `counter` inside function `addInput(...)`, but this variable goes out of scope and loses its value every time the function ends. In order to make it keep its value, you need to declare it *outside* of function `addInput(...)`. You can then increase its value, etc, inside the js function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Peter! What can be the value of divName? I moved the var counter = 1;
   var limit = 20; above function and changed the OnClient but still the button is not working.

Comment: It's the ID of a `<div>` on your page where you want the new elements to be created, that is totally up to you.

Comment: How do you change the value of div? It's my first Javascript code and I'm really confused. Also, why are the fields not being generated when I click the button? Appreciated!